# Why does the Sun appear more round while distant stars can appear more pointed?

Tags: optics, astronomy, atmospheric-science, stars, vision

In a [minute physics video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVAKFJ8VVp4) about the shapes of stars, it mentions that stars in the night sky appear star-shaped due to imperfections in our eyes known as suture lines which cause diffraction.

Then why does the Sun looks round? In a source it is written its because the Sun is too close to Earth. But why does the Sun's closeness to Earth matter?

Comment: Please give a link to the Minute Physics video.

Comment: I am asking why that does not happen to the sun? It seems perfectly round to use. Why diffraction does not occur in case of the sun?

Comment: m.youtube.com/watch?v=VVAKFJ8VVp4 here is the video

Answer (score 3):

### Distant stars are small, [Sol](http://earthsky.org/space/what-is-the-suns-name) is big

Because distant stars are small in our field of vision... they are point-sources of light. Point-sources of light are easily affected by sutures and other imperfections in the eye.

Sol however is not a point-source of light in our field of vision. Sol is **huge** when comparing its apparent size to its distant siblings. And objects that are large in our field of vision are not affected in the same way by imperfections in the eye.

Comment: Regarding the edits that were made: I have reverted to a smaller headline. I **will** use a headline however, because headlines are a great help to readers to quickly get the gist of an answer. Also our nearest star does not have a name, nothing that **requires** us to call it by one or another. As the link I put in shows, Sol is a somewhat poetic name, and I quite like it, so I will use it because 1) it is clear enough that people will understand what I mean and that I am referring to "our" star and 2) it is more beautiful and poetic than "the sun".

Comment: I did not realize your answer was of a poetic nature.

Comment: Also, if the gist of your answer if that stars are small while the sun is big, it's just plain wrong.

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin There is nothing wrong with using poetic language in a physics setting. I wish more people would use it (on condition that their meaning remains clear and unambiguous of course). And regarding what supposedly is "just plain wrong"... please read again. Note the words "in our field of vision" and "**apparent** size". Do you still think the answer "[is] just plain wrong"?

Comment: Neither 'in our field of vision' nor 'apparent size' are in the headline, which should provide (as you said) 'the gist of an answer'.

Comment: Lousy reference. The English name of the star about which our planet orbits is the Sun, with an upper case S. While there are very large number of suns and moons in the universe, there is only one Sun, and only one Moon.

Comment: "_Sol_" and "_Luna_" seem like good names to me.  They're clearly recognizable and mitigate the ambiguity that can come from "_Sun_" and "_Moon_".  I see no advantage in insistence that "_Sun_" and "_Moon_" continue to be used.

Comment: What is the name of our planetary system?  The *Solar* system.  Not the Sun system.  It's *Sol*.

Answer (score 0):

The stars are very distant objects. As the the distance between our eyes and object increases the objects appear smaller. And the stars are at infinite
distance so they appear pointlike sources of the light. If they were of the size of smaller celestial bodies like moon, earth or neptune they would not be visible to our naked eyes, but they are of the size of sun or way more bigger than that.